# Cucumber::Ast::Table: How to correctly handle "inner" rows with :surplus_row?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'd like to compare a Cucumber::Ast::Table of (at least) expected values with an array containing my actual values, but I want to ignore additional rows. For this, I thought I could use the `diff!` method with  `:surplus_row => false`.

This works as expected (Cucumber reports success):

```
table (Cucumber::Ast::Table):

  |id|name |
  |1 |one  |
  |2 |two  |

@actual:
  |id|name |
  |1 |one  |
  |2 |two  |
  |3 |three|
```

But this does not (I get `Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different` ):

```
table (Cucumber::Ast::Table):

  |id|name |
  |2 |two  |

@actual:
  |id|name |
  |1 |one  |
  |2 |two  |
  |3 |three|
```

So it seems Cucumber is reporting a false positive if my @actual contains only "inner" rows. Is this a bug in Cucumber? Or am I making some stupid mistake?

**CODE**

table.feature:

```
Feature: Comparing Cucumber tables

Scenario: Comparing with a table with additional rows
Given I have a table with three rows and two columns
 When I compare this table with an additional row and the same columns
 Then I should get at least these rows
    |id|name |
    |2 |two  |
```

table_steps.rb:

```
Given /^I have a table with three rows and two columns$/ do
  @actual = [ { "id" => "1", "name" => "one" },
              { "id" => "2", "name" => "two"},
              { "id" => "3", "name" => "three" } ]
end

When /^I compare this table with an additional row and the same columns$/ do
  # no-op
end

Then /^I should get at least these rows$/ do |table|
  table.diff!(@actual, { :surplus_row => false } )
end
```

Cucumber version 1.2.1

Comment: I copied your code as is and executed it. Everything went green. Are you saying that `green` is incorrect?

Comment: @Bala No, I'm getting "    | 3  | three |
    Tables were not identical (Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different)
    ./features/steps/table_steps.rb:12:in `/^I should get at least these rows$/'
    features\table.feature:6:in `Then I should get at least these rows'". Which version of cucumber are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in the old cucumber version I was using. Upgrading from 1.2.1 to 1.3.10 fixed the issue.

See [Cucumber Github Issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/220) for details regarding the bug.